# how to send files to sd card with Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I need to send a certificate to android emulator
but I can't find anything to upload the files to the sd card
in the IDE.

How can I send files to the sd card? (So I won't have to keep uploading them to dropbox and open in browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found to send files to android's sd card on emulator was using

android sdk\tools\monitor.bat

it took me sometime to realize that you are not supose to push files into sdcard but to mnt/sdcard/